# JQuery RegEx needed for number format ##.##

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx to validate a number.
The number format is 2digits(optional .digits). E.g: `10`, `22.2`, `1.33`, `1.0`, `99.99`

My regex is:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Remove `+`. `^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `+`:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/mY0qK3/1)</kbd>

Since you are already using the `{1,2}` quantifier, you should not use `+` as well. You can use either one, not both.

You can also optimize your RegEx:

```
^\d\d?(\.\d\d?)?$
```

- `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`
- `\d\d?` is the same as `\d{1,2}`, however it is 2 digits shorter

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oJ3qR4/1)</kbd>